# Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Empty regular expression in C:\xampp

Tags: php

I am trying to output the data to a graph but I am receiving this error on preg_replace statment .

```
ImageTTFText($this->img, $which_font['size'], $which_angle, 
                         $which_xpos, $which_ypos, $which_color, $which_font['font'], $which_text);
        }
        // Fixed fonts:
        else {
            // explode the text by its lines, and count them
            $which_text = preg_replace("\r", "", $which_text);
            $str = explode("\n", $which_text);
            $nlines = count($str);
            $spacing = $this->line_spacing * ($nlines - 1);
```

Comment: Just use `str_replace`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regular expression is `\r` which is invalid; you must have a start/stop delimiter (for example, `/`). Try changing it to `/\r/`:

```
$which_text = preg_replace("/\r/", "", $which_text);
```

Comment: @KiranV Pleasure - glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

You use a wrong syntax for `preg_replace`.
Your string replacement will works fine using a simple `str_replace` function:

```
$which_text = str_replace("\r", "", $which_text);
```

`preg_replace` is intended to use to match complex patterns, like, i.e., ***any** word followed by a space*.

If you want replace a know, exact substring, you have to use `str_replace` instead.

Read more about [`preg_replace` syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Comment: `preg_repace` is used to match **regular expressions**, which is what `\r` is. `str_replace` can't do that.